# products gallery not export in magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport, media-images

I have exported all products from Import/Export >> Dataflow profiles.

but products gallery images are not exported in csv file.

Is there any setting in magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its version issue:

Check these two files you will get answer:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Parser/Product.php
```

This code is missing in your version:

```
$rowMediaGallery = array(
                    '_media_image'          => $image['file'],
                    '_media_lable'          => $image['label'],
                    '_media_position'       => $image['position'],
                    '_media_is_disabled'    => $image['disabled']
                );
```